# network.request and non-english characters

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I am using network.request in corona sdk, i build a string for the url but when this string has spaces, spanish acents, arabic char, japanese char etc...it gives me an error (bad url).
How can i solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Even better than removing the letters is to escape the URL using [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Since Lua only supports 8-bit strings, I guess that the international characters are encoded in something like UTF-8 and your server supports it. Then, you can use the following function from [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html) to `escape` the URL:

```
function escape (s)
  s = string.gsub(s, "([&=+%c\128-\255])", function (c)
        return string.format("%%%02X", string.byte(c))
      end)
  s = string.gsub(s, " ", "+")
  return s
end
print(escape("http://server/aáäbcčdďeé..."))
--> http://server/a%C3%A1%C3%A4bc%C4%8Dd%C4%8Fe%C3%A9...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the strings, spanish chars, etc from the url you build. Urls can't have those characters.